# Android: AppBarLayout with Toolbar layout failure

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a very simple demo app which you can access [on GitHub](https://github.com/Nagilo1/MyToolbar). The main activity contains a toolbar (as the new ActionBar) following the material design guidelines. But you will see, that the fragment is wrong at the bottom - exactly by the height of the toolbar. Do I need to invalidate the layout somehow once the toolbar is set to the activity in onCreate()?

Any idea?

[image: layout problem]

Here's the XML layout for the fragment. It's just putting four images into each of the corners within a relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        >

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            />

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            />

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            />

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

That's the XML layout for the main activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<fragment android:name="com.demo.mytoolbar.MainFragment"
          android:id="@+id/fragment_new_park_item"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
</fragment>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
```

And the code for the main activity. The one for the fragment is just inflating the layout and does nothing else.

package com.demo.mytoolbar;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout was below of toolbar because you set layout_behavior to fragment layout. But if you remove it don't forget that CoordinatorLayout will work like default FrameLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.demo.mytoolbar.MainFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_new_park_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/action_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Ok I'll try that. But I wonder because all intros that I found, had the AppBarLayout on top of XML and the main content just below. See [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout).

Comment: Did you actually test your solution? Because it does not work. Now the main content is behind the toolbar. And if I add the layout_bevahior, then the problem is at the bottom again.

Comment: PS: I somehow fixed it using: app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"